# How to make text appear on specific view ports using visible class in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I just started learning Boots trap, so i am trying to make a responsive page where some div will only appear on specific view ports.
used visible-xs, visible-sm, visible-md and visible-lg for the different DIVs but when i resize the screen the it's not working ?

This the HTML code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/btcss.css"/>
        <title>Bootstrap</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is My first Bootstrap layout</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="visible-xs visible-sm">Extra Small and Small Screen</div>
                <div class="visible-md">Medium Screen</div>
                <div class="visible-lg">Large Screen</div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="visible-xs visible-sm">DIV for Xtra small and small Screens</div>
                    <div class="visible-md">DIV for Middle Screens</div>
                    <div class="visible-lg">DIV for Large Screens</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="visible-xs visible-sm">DIV for Xtra small and small Screens</div>
                    <div class="visible-md">DIV for Middle Screens</div>
                    <div class="visible-lg">DIV for Large Screens</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="visible-xs visible-sm">DIV for Xtra small and small Screens</div>
                    <div class="visible-md">DIV for Middle Screens</div>
                    <div class="visible-lg">DIV for Large Screens</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 [doc on display](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With display classes, you can do what size is visible instead of visible, which size is invisible.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h1>This is My first Bootstrap layout</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="d-sm-block d-md-none">Extra Small and Small Screen</div>
      <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">Medium Screen</div>
      <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">Large Screen</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="d-sm-block d-md-none">DIV for Xtra small and small Screens</div>
      <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">DIV for Middle Screens</div>
      <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">DIV for Large Screens</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="d-sm-block d-md-none">DIV for Xtra small and small Screens</div>
      <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">DIV for Middle Screens</div>
      <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">DIV for Large Screens</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="d-sm-block d-md-none">DIV for Xtra small and small Screens</div>
      <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">DIV for Middle Screens</div>
      <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">DIV for Large Screens</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```